# Creating a Halton sequence in Octave

Tags: octave

I want to create a vector containing `M` "uniformly" distributed numbers on[0,1] using Halton sequence. I think I did it like in [wikipedia][1].

```
  u=double(zeros(M,1));      
  for index= 1:M
        i=index;
        r=0;
        f=1;
        while true
          if not(i>0)
            break;
          end
          f=double(f)./double(base);
          r=r+f.*(mod(i,base));
          i= floor(double(i)./double(base));
        endwhile
        u(index)=r;
```

This is the solution, thanks to the post below.

Comment: I am using octave, that's why I changed the division to double. I thought code is more or less the same.

Comment: It's "more or less" the same indeed, but does have differences, such as the one you mentioned here.

Comment: If you think the answer below is help, please feel free to upvote/accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pseudocode of Halton sequence, I guess you can adjust your `while` loop a bit like below and retry

```
while true
  if not(index>0 && number<M+1)
    break;
  end
  f=double(f)./double(base);
  r=r+f.*(mod(index,base))
  index= floor(index./base); 
  u(number)=r;
  number=number+1;
end
```